# Prove $\nabla f$ is orthogonal to the surface $f$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove that $\nabla f$ is orthogonal to the surface $f$. I think I have a valid proof but I'm not sure that it is rigorous.

To prove $\nabla f$ is normal  I am proving that $\nabla f\cdot u=0$ for any vector $u$ tangent to the surface $f$. Say $z=f(x,y)$ then $\nabla f$ $= \left(\begin{array}{c}
\delta_x\\
\delta_y\end{array}\right)$ and choosing any vector $v=(v_1,v_2)$ we need to construct the tangent vector to the surface. The tangent vector is $(v_1,v_2,f'_u$(**x**)).

We achieve $f'_u$(**x**) from $\nabla f\cdot u$ which gives us $f'_u$(**x**)$= v_1\delta_x + v_2\delta_y$. Therefore the tangent vector is $u=(v_1,v_2,v_1\delta_x+v_2\delta_y)$. Now we can dot $\nabla f$ with $u$.

However now I came across the problem that we had one vector with 3 rows and one with 2 rows. Therefore I redefined $\nabla f$ and called a new fucntion $g(x,y,z)=f(x,y)-z$ at the level set $g(x,y,z)=0$. Now $\nabla g$ has three components and $$\nabla g=(\delta_x,\delta_y,-1)$$ I then took the dot product of $\nabla g$ and $u$ and this gave $$v_1\delta_x+v_2\delta_y-(v_1\delta_x+v_2\delta_y)=0$$ Therefore $\nabla g$ is orthogonal to the level set $g(x,y,z)=0$ and by equivalence $\nabla f$ is orthogonal to the surface $f(x,y)$.

Now that is I'm guessing that's a long way round but would you class it as rigorous? Any suggestions to improve it? Is there any way to not have to use $g(x,y,z)$?

Thanks

Comment: You mean the surface $\{x\,:\,f(x)=0\}$?

Comment: if I read you proof correctly, what you have done is to consider the particular case that $F=0$ (my lingo) is of the form $z=f(x,y)$. You then observe that the $x,y$ coordinate curves have tangents with which we can build any other tangent vector. In view of that basis expansion, you then show that the the gradient of $(you) g=F (me)$ is perpendicular. I think this is ok if you are sure the reader can see that your expression of the tangent vector is general. I took as the definition of the tangent space it is the union of all curve tangents. How do you define the tangent space?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the level surface $F(x,y,z)=k$. If $\alpha: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow S$ is a curve on the surface then $F(\alpha (t))=k$ for all $t$. But, the chain-rule for multivariate calculus says $\nabla F(\alpha(t)) \cdot \alpha'(t)=0$ for all $t$. Thus, for any time $t_o$ we find the tangent $\alpha'(t_o)$ is perpendicular to $\nabla F(\alpha(t_o))$. But, the curve is arbitrary as is the point and this suffices to show $\nabla F$ is perpendicular to any tangent vector to the level surface $F^{-1}\{k \}$.

Comment: I thought the multivariate chain rule was used to find the derivative of $f$ along a path/curve $r(t)$ and therefore is not always zero.

Comment: The general multivariate chain rule for $F: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ and $G: \mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is elegant expressed as $(F o G)' = F'G'$ where $F',G'$ are Jacobian matrices for $F$ and $G$ respective and that formula denotes matrix multiplication.